# Different Results with Different PCs: Run Time Error 91 Object Variable or With Block Not Set

Tags: vba, excel

I run the code below in two different PCs while get two different result: one works fine, another reminds "run time error 91 object variable or with block not set". Can anybody help me out?

```
Function FindArchiveFile() As String 

FindArchiveFile = Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Filelist").UsedRange, _
    Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B")).Find( _
    CDate(WorksheetFunction.Large(Workshee‌​ts("Filelist").Range("B:B"), 2))).Offset(0, -1).Value 

Worksheets("Setting").Range("LastDate").Value = _
    Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Filelist").UsedRange,  _
    Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B")).Find( _
    CDate(WorksheetFunction.Large(Workshee‌ts("Filelist").Range("B:B"), 2))).Value 

End Function
```

Comment: You have too many parentheses in the wrong places.  Please post more of your code.  Aside from such a syntax error (which will not allow the code to run at all), it's quite impossible to determine what might be causing the specific error.  What makes you think it is *this particular line of code* that is raising the error?  We really need to see more.

Comment: `Function FindArchiveFile() As String

    FindArchiveFile = Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Filelist").UsedRange, Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B")).Find(CDate(WorksheetFunction.Large(Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B"), 2))).Offset(0, -1).Value
    Worksheets("Setting").Range("LastDate").Value = Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Filelist").UsedRange, Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B")).Find(CDate(WorksheetFunction.Large(Worksheets("Filelist").Range("B:B"), 2))).Value
    
End Function`

Comment: Sorry for the messy formatting. Can anyone help me correct it? I don't know how to add codes in reply.

Comment: I put your code in the question. This is a Function; how are you calling the function?  Are you calling it from another subroutine/macro or is it being called from the worksheet in a cell,  like `=FindArchiveFile()`?

Comment: It would also help to have an idea of what the data looks like on the Worksheet. Upload an image to http://imgur.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I've revised your function to make it more human-readable.  This should work with some caveats.

**If you are calling this function from a worksheet,** it is unlikely to work.

- This is because a workhseet function can generally only return a value to the calling cell. It cannot otherwise manipulate the worksheet objects.  This function is trying to set a value in a named range `"LastDate"` and this is likely to fail.  It may fail silently on this line and still return the value to the calling cell.
- This function when called from a worksheet will likely raise a Circular Reference Error

When called from a subroutine, this function appears to work, or at least it does not return an error for me.

```
Sub Test()
'Use this to test the function
MsgBox FindArchiveFile
Worksheets("Setting").Range("LastDate").Value = FindArchiveFile
End Sub

Function FindArchiveFile() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rngInt As Range
    Dim foundVal As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Filelist") 
    Set rngB = ws.Range("B:B")
    Set rngInt = Application.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rngB)

    foundVal = rngInt.Find( _
        CDate(WorksheetFunction.Large(rngB, 2))).Offset(0, -1).Value

    '## I comment the next line out and put it in the calling subroutine, since
    '   the function returns a value, use the function properly.
    'Worksheets("Setting").Range("LastDate").Value = foundVal

    FindArchiveFile = IIf(foundVal = vbNullString, "Not Found", foundVal)

End Function
```